# How to redirect htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

All links from my main page return a 404 error, i am using 3 htaccess files one in the top level folder, one each in the next level folders. my site is based on an mvc Framework and the htaccess files should redirect everything through the main index.php in a folder named public. All the server code is in a folder named app. both folders are Inside the main folder. I have looked at all the questions on here regarding htaccess and also on the web but can't find any answers that work for me.  The htaccess code seems to read right to me but i am relatively new to this! All help greatly apprecieted.

I have tried lots of different ways of writing the htaccess code, I have read tutorials on htaccess and followed the rules which seem to work okay on my local server. I am probably doing Something really simple wrong but i can't figure it out.

```
 // htaccess file in top folder
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 // code in public folder
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /public/TicketApp
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule  ^(.\*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>

  // code in app folder
  Options -Indexes
```

404 error on page when i click on the link but main page will load if i put in the extensions in the browser else it returns a 403 error of forbidden

Comment: Maybe the rewriting module is not installed or not made available for your site? Have you checked that? How?

Comment: It says on their site and I have also telephoned them many times to confirm all this as i read about all the different scenarios, that rewrite modules are available by default and also the OverrideAll is set to all, I just don't get it. I have studied the code for htaccess and from what i have found on the internet the code seems to work out right.

Comment: What do you mean by "what I have found on the internet"? There is a documentation. That is the only thing you need to take a look at. It is more precise than anything else. And it comes with good examples.

Comment: I have looked at various tutorials and understand it, but a lot of what i thought should work didn't, i have now managed to get most of the site working.  now just working on the root folder it is giving me a forbidden error.  I will get there eventually.

Comment: It all works now.

Comment: So you should post your final solution for others who come over your question.

Comment: And really, believe me, the documentation makes more sense to read than various tutorials...